# How to convert Unix Timestamp to readable timestamp in AIX 5.3

Tags: perl, unix

I have a file with the below contents.

```
   MAX_FRAG_SIZE 1
   ACTIVE 3
   EFFECTIVE_TIME 1279057213
   COLLECT_TIR_INFO 1
   EXTENDED_SECURITY_INFO 3
   EFFECTIVE_TIME 1279057324
   ENABLE_PFI 0
   OFFHOST_BACKUP 0
```

The second field of EFFECTIVE_TIME is the timestamp. How can we convert the second field of EFFECTIVE_TIME into human readable format and replace it in the file itself. Also the strftime() function doesn't works in AIX 5.3.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: AIX 5.3 is long dead (end of service was [April 2012](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012517)).  You should be able to use some of the other time functions if you're really sure that `strftime()` doesn't work (though I'm surprised to hear that it doesn't, even in an older system like AIX 5.3).  The `gmtime` and `localtime` functions will work; you can use `sprintf` to format the result to suit yourself — that's what `strtime` does behind the scenes.

Comment: Maybe http://www.aixhealthcheck.com/blog?id=236 will help you. There is also an example, how to convert timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly, 'strftime' works in AIX5.3. So does strtol, localtime_r, sprintf and other useful functions.

Also, you can install GNU!date, it can convert from timestamp to human readable form:

```
$ gdate --date='@1279057324'
Tue Jul 13 23:42:04 CEST 2010
```